# Real world pre/post-order tree traversal examples

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal, postorder

I understand pre-order, in-order, and post-order tree traversal algorithms just fine. ([Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)).  I understand a few uses: in-order for traversing binary search trees in order, pre-order for cloning a tree.  But I can't for the life of me come up with a real world task that I'd need post-order traversal to accomplish.

Can you give me an example?  And: can you give me any better uses for pre-order traversal?

Edit: Can anyone give me an example other than expression trees and RPN?  Is that really all post-order is good for?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) is a post-order traversal of trees (or directed acyclic graphs).

The idea is that the nodes of the graph represent tasks and an edge from `A` to `B` indicates that `A` has to be performed before `B`. A topological sort will arrange these tasks in a sequence such that all the dependencies of a task appear earlier than the task itself. Any build system like [UNIX make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) has to implement this algorithm.

The example that Dario mentioned — destroying all nodes of a tree with manual memory management — is an instance of this problem. After all, the task of destroying a node depends on the destruction of its children.

Comment: This is a great answer.  Remembering that trees are degenerate graphs opens up all kinds of functionality.  And topological sorting is hugely useful.

Comment: Why is it called topological sorting instead of, say, scheduling or something, or what is "Topological" supposed to mean in this context?

Comment: @Shawn: Beats me. It's probably because only the topology of the graph/network matters.

Answer (score 4):

As Henk Holterman pointed out, destroying a tree using manual memory management usually is a post-order traversal.

Pseudocode:

```
destroy(node) {
  if (node == null) return;

  destroy(node.left)
  destroy(node.right)

  // Post-order freeing of current node
  free(node)
}
```